# Python: How to toggle an object visibility with a menu?

Tags: python, scripting

Hello everyone I was making a menu for my rig in python, so I was wondering how would I make a menu that can toggle visibility of certain objects according to the option I choose:
[image]

For example, let’s say I have “Object 1” and “Object 2” as you can see in the image, and I want that when you select “Slot 1” it only shows “Object 1” and when you select “Slot 2” it only shows “Object 2” and so on (Ignore the “Default” option).

How would I do that? I’m very noob on python…